# Странное поведение при переполнении, зависящее от уровня оптимизации

Tags: c++

Возьмём код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char xi;
    unsigned char xf;
    int   bi = -300;
    float bf = -300;
    xi = bi;
    xf = bf;
    printf("xi = %d\n", xi);
    printf("xf = %d\n", xf);

    return 0;
}
```

[получаем](http://cpp.sh/2ezyi) вывод:

```
xi = 212
xf = 0
```

хотя ожидалось, что `unsigned char` корректно переполнится и обе переменные окажутся равны `212`. Что интересно, при наличии флага `-O0` (без оптимизации) получается вывод как и ожидалось:

```
xi = 212
xf = 212
```

при флаге `-O1` и выше уже появляется отличие.

По-видимому, я здесь наступил на какой-то вариант неопределённого поведения, подскажите, что именно здесь произошло? Где косяк?

PS. При переполнии "вверх" на выводе получается 255, если через `float` пропустить, как в примере.

Comment: Есть тип переменной, есть тип литерала. У вас тип литерала и тип переменной отличаются - поэтому происходят преобразования, которые в зависимости от опций - могут быть разными. Для float следует использовать запись с точкой `-300.0` либо литеральный суффикс f т.е. `-300f` Если откроете исходники многих библиотек (например стандартные библиотеки) - встретите такие записи.

Comment: Если правка литерала - не изменила поведения - то нужно читать что за оптимизиция и сравнивать ассемблерный код - тогда будет понятно поведение. Да, ещё, какой компилятор используется?

Comment: Допускаю такое поведение. Ваши `bi` и `bf` могут быть сокращены. Если сокращение не произошло, то -300 преобразуется в целое и записывается в unsigned char с "обрезанием битов". Если происходит оптимизация - то код bi `unsigned char bf = -300;` более понятен компилятору - нужно выполнить одно преобразование, а код bf - зачёркиваем и получаем   `unsigned char bf = -300.0f;`   возможно  вместо того что б преобразовать и в целое и в положительное - компилятор счёл что float число выходит за границы ОДЗ [0,255] и решил воовсе не конвертировать.

Comment: Компилятор gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Переполнение при *целочисленном* преобразовании в беззнаковый тип подчиняется правилам [Integral conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3), т.е. обрабатывается как обычно, по правилам модульной арифметики.

Переполнение при *плавающем* преобразовании в беззнаковый тип подчиняется правилам [Floating-integral conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1) - т.е. это неопределенное поведение.

Вот и вся разница. Нет ничего "странного" в том, что проявления неопределенного поведения меняются в зависимости от настроек компилятора.

Answer (score 12):

Это неопределенное поведение. Тип назначения должен вмещать значение источника.

см. [`[conv.fpint]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint)

> The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.